# ggplot with the same width and height as ggsave(width=x, height=y)

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Within R-Studio, I am generating plots with `ggplot`, then I save them with `ggsave()` for further use (I know, not ideal, but non-optional right now).

My problem is that when I generate the plot before saving it, R shows it to me in a particular size. With `ggsave`, I set `width` and `height`, so the elements displayed shift etc. I only see this ***after*** saving the plot.

I want R to show it to me before. I thus assume that I need to set the size of the plot within `ggplot()` somewhere , not in `ggsave()`.

How can I do this in the least complicated fashion?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point() +
  labs(title="Rocket science title that will get cut by ggsave")

ggsave("rocketScience.png", width=10, height=7, unit="cm")
```

Comment: You need to set the width and height of the graphics device. See `?dev.new` and `?Devices`

Comment: Note that this may be a place where your operating system and your IDE matter - one of the rare questions where adding the RStudio tag might be appropriate if you are using RStudio.

Comment: I have looked at it and I don't get how that would solve this problem/ be applied.I was hoping for a simple setting within ggplot(). Can you demonstrate using the working example above?

Comment: ggplot don't track size information. They expand to fill your graphics device. So you can only really set that in ggsave(). Are you using R or RStudio? If you have a graphics device window open for preview, you can look at the width/height of that preview and use that same ratio inside the ggsave.

Comment: R-Studio. I have tried that now. Unfortunately, there is still a difference, even when I adjust the window where the graph is shown to the approx. size of the outputed png.

Comment: My workflow is usually that I create the finished plot, then save with ggsave, check result and adjust text/symbol sizes and resolution. The latter two steps are iterated until I'm happy with the result. I believe that's the best approach because AFAIK you can't create the same resolution in other graphics devices.

Comment: Have a look at the `set_panel_size()` function from the egg package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Overview.html .
Might not be exactly what you were looking for, but might solve the problem in some situations.

Comment: If you're on windows, you can use `windows()` to create a device (a new pop-up graphics window) with specified width, height, etc., then you can print the plot to that device. It's possible, but not any easier than saving a file and iterating on the file. A key to a good workflow is setting your image/PDF viewers to ones that will auto-update if the file changes. On windows, I like Sumatra for PDF files and ImageGlass for rasters.

Comment: This code just returns gibberish and no image ```p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_point() +
  labs(title="Rocket science title that will get cut by ggsave") 

set_panel_size(p=a, width=unit(10, "cm"), height=unit(7, "cm"))```

Comment: I added an answer illustrating the use of `set_panel_size()`. Does this help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `set_panel_size()` function from the [egg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Overview.html) package. 
With this function you can fix the panel size of the plot. This can be very useful when creating multiple plots that should have the exact same plotting area but use varying axis labels or something similar that would usually slightly change the panel dimensions. Especially useful for presentations with seamless animations or publications. It also ensures the same dimensions in the preview and the saved plot.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title="Rocket science title that will get cut by ggsave")

#to view the plot
gridExtra::grid.arrange(egg::set_panel_size(p=p, width=unit(5, "cm"), height=unit(7, "cm")))

#to save the plot
ggsave(filename = "myplot.pdf", plot = egg::set_panel_size(p=p, width=unit(5, "cm"), height=unit(7, "cm")))
```

Within ggsave you can still manipulate the size of the whole "page" saved, but this will only influence the amount of white space around the plot. The actual panel size will stay fixed.
The example plot from above with 5cm or 15cm as width:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is achievable via ggplot settings; you might get around it if using RMarkdown, as you *can* set with and height of an output of a markdown chunk via `fig.width` and `fig.height` params.

[image]

Comment: Have tried that now, the output is not adjusted according to those specifications in my case.

Comment: That is strange...  fig.width and fig.height (always numeric, always in inches) *should* work in preview mode. out.width and out.height (can accept other units, i.e. pixels & centimeters) work only when actual output is produced